# How would you show different action widgets using DefaultTabController based on which tab is selected?

Tags: flutter

I really like how DefaultTabController can manage multiple screens as tabs, but is there a way that we can show different action widgets depending on what tab is selected? For example in the picture attached, if I selected the Food tab I see the Refresh action widget. If I select the Drinks tab, I'd like to change the action widget to a Create instead?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text(
        'Demo',
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.refresh,
          ),
          label: Text(
            'Refresh',
          ),
        ),
      ],
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(text: 'Food'),
          Tab(text: 'Drinks'),
          Tab(text: 'Snacks'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Food(),
        Drinks(),
        Snacks (),
      ],
    ),
```

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7RPX.png)

Comment: Why not store the selected tab in your state, and update it when the selected tab changes. Then you can use that state to decide which action button to display.

Comment: use a tab controller to update the action button